# What gotcha's exist when working with transient in Clojure 1.3?

Tags: performance, clojure

I'm looking into techniques to speed up my application and I'm trying out Transients. I know I'm supposed to treat them with some caution, but what are the kinds of issues that arise?

Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use transients like the usual persistent data structures - that is, always use the return value from a mutator instead of the structure you called the mutator on. However, don't trust that the old version stays the same, and don't access transients from other threads.

Comment: I would add: use transients only during structure construction. Then turn them into "normal", persistent structures for access, query, etc.

Comment: "and don't access transients from other threads"  You can't anyway.  If you try to, an exception will be thrown.

Comment: so purely for structure construction? Never for transformation? So if I'm taking some pre-existing data that I just read from a file and need to turn it into a data structure for use this is inappropriate? Or does that fall under structure construction?

Comment: As far as documentation says, transformations should be OK (otherwise there whould be no `transient` function).